# Как правильно указать путь к папке на телефоне, куда нужно сохранить файл с FTP-сервера?

Tags: c#, xamarin, ftp

Скачиваю файл с FTP по нажатию кнопки в папку на телефоне. Как правильно указать эту папку?

```
button.Click += delegate {
            string inputfilepath = @"/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.txt"; //путь к папке на телефоне
            string ftpfullpath = "ftp://ххх/ххх/1.txt";

            using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
            {
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
                byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(ftpfullpath);

                using (FileStream file = File.Create(inputfilepath)) //здесь выдает исключение Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.txt" is denied
                {
                    file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                    file.Close();
                }

            }

        };
```

Comment: 1. Для таких целей обычно используются методы/свойства среды, которую используете. Например в Android есть [Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), а у самого Xamarin есть [System.Environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/platform/files/). 2. Для доступа к таким папкам нужны права (если я не ошибаюсь это `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`/`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`), они у вас есть (судя по Access denied нет...)?

Comment: в том то и дело, эти разрешения у меня подключены) а вот по поводу методов,которые Вы написали, может быть у Вас есть пример, как можно это сделать иначе, используя эти методы?)

Comment: Вот на [официальном форуме](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21392/download-file-to-download-directory) Xamarin'a люди про ту же проблему разговаривают, может что у них почерпнете.

Comment: Ошибка у вас не полная, смотрите что конкретней пишет, ибо сейчас это просто "произошла ошибка". Ну и сама ошибка, это уже проблема в работе с сервером, а не изначальный ваш вопрос про доступ к директории. Также, если у вас есть дополнение по вопросу (ваш код из комментария), то стоит добавлять все в сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), ибо здесь читать такое довольно неудобно.  Ну а вообще, если это уже проблема в работе с сервером, то наверно на основной вопрос (доступ к директории) вы нашли ответ и его стоит написать в виде ответа, а работу с сервером стоит другим вопросом описать.

Comment: большое спасибо) создала другой вопрос) я пока плохо разобралась с этой системой комментариев)